# Making a LiveData to observe multiple retrofit requests in same View

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, android-livedata

I am using Retrofit 2.0 along with MVVM pattern in kotlin and I am able to observe API results from Retrofit through the repository and ViewModel in my activity.

Now my question is that for each API call I have to create a separate LiveData in ViewModel and parallelly a separate observer for each LiveData in my Activity which I feel is duplicating my code. I feel that same LiveData in ViewModel can be observed in Activity but the main problem is to identify the API response of each request. Is there any way to identify this? If yes I just need a create a single observer and i can handle the response of each API on the basis of this identifier.

I have read a lot about this on various blogs but none of them is giving a clear picture of the best practice. Requesting everyone here to enlighten my path and help me to do this in the best possible way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you add multiple response types inside single `LiveData`? In my opinion taking `Any` is highly discouraged.

Comment: Okay..Is there any performance related issue?

Comment: Don't think so of any, because now you'll just have to provide some condition in observer to determine your desired response from multiple responses.

Comment: Do work with states(InProgress,Success,Failed) for your requests? May work with a (Pair)Mediator (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) or work with Flows and Combine (https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-how-to-combine-kotlin-flows-317849a71d3e)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a state parameter with an enum or sealed class like this :

```
enum class State { ApiOneSuccess, ApiTwoSuccess, Error }
```

and then you make LiveData of this state in your ViewModel :

```
val liveState = MutableLiveData<State>()
```

I dont know what you use for API callback, but you should put `liveState.postValue(ApiOneSuccess)`in your onSuccess callback for your first API and do the same for onError and second API

then you can observe this LiveData in onCreate of your activity and do the proper actions:

```
viewModel.liveState.observe(this) { state ->
            state?.also {
                when (it) {
                    ApiOneSuccess -> { // do what you need to do }
                    ApiOneSuccess -> { // do what you need to do }
                    Error -> { // do what you need to do }
                }
                viewModel.liveState.postValue(null)
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope the concept is clear for you

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I have already done this..

Comment: this way you dont have to create a live data for each api, you just create one liveData, thats what I understood